# Angular route navigation with variable param

Tags: angular

I have some routes in my app.module.ts :

```
 {path: 'infos/:lang', loadChildren: './base-infos/base-infos.module#BaseInfosModule' },
  {path: '', redirectTo: 'infos/fr', pathMatch: 'full' }
```

And iam calling the first route in my code :

```
this._router.navigate(['infos/', this.currentLang ])
```

If i choose the language english, so "this.currentLang" equals to "en" in the url "infos/en". The issue is, even if i choose "en" it always leads me to "infos/fr" instead of "infos/en".

Is there any reason why my code is doing this ???
thanks

Comment: whats if you hard code `this._router.navigate(['infos','en'])`. Does it still go to the `fr` route? I am betting it won't, which means that someone is setting `this.currentLang` to `fr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for first try place the route with `path: ''` above the another route, like that:

```
{path: '', redirectTo: 'infos/fr', pathMatch: 'full' }, 
{path: 'infos/:lang', loadChildren: './base-infos/base-infos.module#BaseInfosModule' }
```

or also try this `router.navigate` function:

```
this._router.navigate([`infos/${ this.currentLang }`]);
```

or also you can try it without the `/` symbol:

```
this._router.navigate(['infos', this.currentLang ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need trailing '/' in navigate call. Try below line

```
this._router.navigate(['infos', this.currentLang ])
```